# Export DataGridView to HTML Page

Tags: c#, html, .net, datagridview, export

I have tried to find an answer to this question and I have not had any success. My issue is this. I have a comboBox that lists different formats to export a report to. One of those options is HTML. Basically what I want to do is take the dataGridView in a windows form and export as is to an HTML page. I would like to just export to an HTML table. I don't even know how to start on this so I don't have any sample code to provide. I am using c sharp 2008 windows app. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private StringBuilder DataGridtoHTML(DataGridView dg)
{
  StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
  //create html & table
  strB.AppendLine("<html><body><center><" + 
                "table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
  strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
  //cteate table header
  for (int i = 0; i < dg.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
     strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" + 
                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>");
   }
  //create table body
  strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
  for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dg.Rows[i].Cells)
    {
        strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" + 
                        dgvc.Value.ToString() + "</td>");
    }
    strB.AppendLine("</tr>");

}
//table footer & end of html file
strB.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
return strB;}
```

The code above is from the link below but I am just giving you what you need which is DataGridView to HTML conversion.

[DataGridView to Email](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23640/How-to-send-DataGridView-contents-by-email)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method I coded up that includes the DataGridView's formatting:

```
public string ConvertDataGridViewToHTMLWithFormatting(DataGridView dgv)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //create html & table
    sb.AppendLine("<html><body><center><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
    //create table header
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(DGVHeaderCellToHTMLWithFormatting(dgv, i));
        sb.Append(DGVCellFontAndValueToHTML(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText, dgv.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Font));
        sb.AppendLine("</td>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
    //create table body
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dgv.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
        foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(DGVCellToHTMLWithFormatting(dgv, rowIndex, dgvc.ColumnIndex));
            string cellValue = dgvc.Value == null ? string.Empty : dgvc.Value.ToString();
            sb.AppendLine(DGVCellFontAndValueToHTML(cellValue, dgvc.Style.Font));
            sb.AppendLine("</td>");
        }
        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }
    //table footer & end of html file
    sb.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
    return sb.ToString();
}

//TODO: Add more cell styles described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0(v=vs.110).aspx
public string DGVHeaderCellToHTMLWithFormatting(DataGridView dgv, int col)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<td");
    sb.Append(DGVCellColorToHTML(dgv.Columns[col].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor, dgv.Columns[col].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor));
    sb.Append(DGVCellAlignmentToHTML(dgv.Columns[col].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment));
    sb.Append(">");
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellToHTMLWithFormatting(DataGridView dgv, int row, int col)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<td");
    sb.Append(DGVCellColorToHTML(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.ForeColor, dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor));
    sb.Append(DGVCellAlignmentToHTML(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.Alignment));
    sb.Append(">");
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellColorToHTML(Color foreColor, Color backColor)
{
    if (foreColor.Name == "0" && backColor.Name == "0") return string.Empty;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" style=\"");
    if (foreColor.Name != "0" && backColor.Name != "0")
    {
        sb.Append("color:#");
        sb.Append(foreColor.R.ToString("X2") + foreColor.G.ToString("X2") + foreColor.B.ToString("X2"));
        sb.Append("; background-color:#");
        sb.Append(backColor.R.ToString("X2") + backColor.G.ToString("X2") + backColor.B.ToString("X2"));
    }
    else if (foreColor.Name != "0" && backColor.Name == "0")
    {
        sb.Append("color:#");
        sb.Append(foreColor.R.ToString("X2") + foreColor.G.ToString("X2") + foreColor.B.ToString("X2"));
    }
    else //if (foreColor.Name == "0" &&  backColor.Name != "0")
    {
        sb.Append("background-color:#");
        sb.Append(backColor.R.ToString("X2") + backColor.G.ToString("X2") + backColor.B.ToString("X2"));
    }

    sb.Append(";\"");
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellFontAndValueToHTML(string value,Font font)
{
    //If no font has been set then assume its the default as someone would be expected in HTML or Excel
    if (font == null || font == this.Font && !(font.Bold | font.Italic | font.Underline | font.Strikeout)) return value;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" ");
    if (font.Bold) sb.Append("<b>");
    if (font.Italic) sb.Append("<i>");
    if (font.Strikeout) sb.Append("<strike>");

    //The <u> element was deprecated in HTML 4.01. The new HTML 5 tag is: text-decoration: underline
    if (font.Underline) sb.Append("<u>");

    string size = string.Empty;
    if (font.Size != this.Font.Size) size = "font-size: " + font.Size + "pt;";

    //The <font> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS or a span instead. 
    if (font.FontFamily.Name != this.Font.Name)
    {
        sb.Append("<span style=\"font-family: ");
        sb.Append(font.FontFamily.Name);
        sb.Append("; ");
        sb.Append(size);
        sb.Append("\">");
    }
    sb.Append(value);
    if (font.FontFamily.Name != this.Font.Name) sb.Append("</span>");

    if (font.Underline) sb.Append("</u>");
    if (font.Strikeout) sb.Append("</strike>");
    if (font.Italic) sb.Append("</i>");
    if (font.Bold) sb.Append("</b>");

    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellAlignmentToHTML(DataGridViewContentAlignment align)
{
    if (align == DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet) return string.Empty;

    string horizontalAlignment = string.Empty;
    string verticalAlignment = string.Empty;
    CellAlignment(align, ref horizontalAlignment, ref verticalAlignment);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" align='");
    sb.Append(horizontalAlignment);
    sb.Append("' valign='");
    sb.Append(verticalAlignment);
    sb.Append("'");
    return sb.ToString();
}

private void CellAlignment(DataGridViewContentAlignment align, ref string horizontalAlignment, ref string verticalAlignment)
{
    switch (align)
    {
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
            horizontalAlignment = "right";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
            horizontalAlignment = "centre";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
            horizontalAlignment = "centre";
            verticalAlignment = "top";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
            horizontalAlignment = "centre";
            verticalAlignment = "bottom";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft:
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "top";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "bottom";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
            horizontalAlignment = "right";
            verticalAlignment = "top";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
            horizontalAlignment = "right";
            verticalAlignment = "bottom";
            break;

        default: //DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it also exports the formatting